# Set a default environment variable in Symfony

Tags: symfony

I am using Symfony 3.4 and I am trying to set a default value for an environment variable:

I have a `.env` file at the root of my project containing:

```
DB_PASSWORD=someValue
```

and in my `app/config/parameters.yml`, I have the following:

```
parameters:
    ...
    database_password: '%env(DB_PASSWORD)%'
    ...
```

I would like to make the definition of the `DB_PASSWORD` variable optionnal in the `.env` file, but I can't find any documentation about how to do such a thing.

I tried to do the following:

```
parameters:
    ...
    database_password: '%env(DB_PASSWORD, "default")%'
    ...
```

without success.

**How can I define a default value for an environment variable in Symfony?**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You just have to declare `env(DB_PASSWORD): default_value` in your `parameters.yml` as stated in the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/configuration/external_parameters.html)

> You can also give the env() parameters a default value: the default
>   value will be used whenever the corresponding environment variable is
>   not found:

```
# app/config/parameters.yml
parameters:
    database_host: '%env(DATABASE_HOST)%'
    env(DATABASE_HOST): localhost
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `default` prefix on env variable in `yaml` config files.

```yaml
parameters:
    ...

    database_password: '%env(default:fallback_db_password:DB_PASSWORD)%'
    ...
```